# Copy SharePoint file from Http to Ftp

Tags: development, client-object-model, csom, .net

Is there a direct way to copy a file from a SharePoint library to an Ftp location?

Currently, I'm able to download the document to a local directory using the `OpenBinaryDirect` method, however this only seems to take local paths, and not ftp://

Similarly, I can upload the file to ftp from a local directory using `FtpWebRequest`, however it cant I can't use a http:// source as a string or variable.

This snippet downloads the file to a local directory:

`var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\%localpath%\file.doc", FileMode.Create);
 f.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);`

This snippet permits me to upload to an ftp location:

`StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"C:\%localpath%\file.doc");`

I'd like to reference the sharepoint https source directly using `OpenBinaryDirect` or reference the ftp destination using `FtpWebRequest`.

Edit: `HttpWebRequest` has the same limitations as `FtpWebRequest`;

Answer (score 2):

Why don´t you use "OpenBinary" Methode of SPFile, hold the stream in Memory and save it to the ftp-Server?

Comment: FtpWebRequest seems to only accept local file parameters - it doesn't appear to accept variables.

Comment: As I can on the MSDN-page of ftpwebrequest, they are reading a local file into a stream and Hand this stream to the ftpwebrequest. sou you should be able to Hand over a stream, no matter where it Comes from.